# Why won't my model save using mongoose and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a simple Post model and a route to create posts at. When I create one using postman, it loads for a bit and then I get the error json back. A model is never saved.

here is the model:

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    data: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});
```

here is the route:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.title);
    console.log(req.body.body);

    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.body
    });

    post.save()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        res.json(post);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

Everything needed is imported. Please help!

Comment: Sorry, do you have model `Post` defined for example: `const Post = db.model('Post', PostSchema);` And can you show me an error?

Comment: What happens? Do you see any errors? Does the code run successfully? Also, Are you sure you've properly connected to your database? Finally, I don't think you are using `save` correctly. When I look at the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) it doesn't appear `save` actually returns a promise. Also, please show us your imports and exports for each of these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a try{}catch{} like this let me know if there is still an error

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = new Post({
      title: req.body.title,
      body: req.body.body,
    });

    post.save();
    res.status(200).send(`Post created!`);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Also check your model is being exported

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    data: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Comment: Setting it up like that with the try catch worked! But now nothing ever shows up in my mongodb DB despite the creation and 200 status code. My DB url is correct, any ideas?? EDIT: had to create a DB in my cluster myself, solved thank you!!